# How does bluetooth sniff mode work?

Tags: bluetooth

I wanted to know exactly how does bluetooth sniff mode work.
Is this special mode going to affect data rates?

Is it used in active transmissions or in idle mode? I am a bit confused.

Comment: Please post documentation. Where did you read the term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know all the details you might want to read the [this document](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=125640).
Beware that that documentation is **extremely technical** as it is intended for communications and system engineers.

But in a nutshell:

- No sniffmode will not influence the datarate as it is **not used** while transferrig data to the device.
- It is used in one of the idle/sleep modes when no active communications is ongoing.
- Snifmode is used to see what other devices are active within the area.